# Unable to add device credentials set up in Watson IoT to your IoT device

Tags: iot, watson-iot

[image: device]I am using my mobile phone as a IoT device and I was able to access the URL from my phone however the device does not appear as connected in Watson IoT. Based on the below screen shot I need to understand how to add the credentials to my phone. I trying to access the link but its not bringing in the correct result.

Answer (score 0):

You need to connect the device (your phone) to the messaging endpoint either via MQTT (the primary protocol) or HTTP. To do this either requires writing code to run on your phone or to use an application to do it for you. You would then use the credentials you mentioned when connecting to the platform.

You didn't say what OS your phone is using but if it is Android then here is a recipe for using an app on Android to connect: https://developer.ibm.com/recipes/tutorials/connect-an-android-device-as-a-managed-device-in-the-iot-foundation-using-tasker/ and here is a link to the docs on general device connectivity: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSQP8H/iot/platform/devices/mqtt.html